# Triple integrals in spherical coordinates, volume of octant

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

So, the question is :
$S$ is the part of the sphere $ρ=a$ cut by the planes $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$ in the first octant. Find the volume of $S$.
I am taking the integration limits as  $0≤\theta≤\frac{\pi}{6}$ and  $0≤\phi≤\frac{\pi}{2}$ and  $0\le \rho \le a$.
Is this correct? And why do we take the $\phi$ limits from $0$ to $\pi$? Why not ${2}{\pi}$? I mean the point can be in the fourth and third octants too.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Toby Mak mathjax not working....

Comment: You probably added an extra \ after $a$.

Comment: Yes I did @Toby Mak thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those limit values are correct.

$\phi$ is the angle from the positive $z$-axis, when $\phi=0$, we are pointing at the positive $z$-axis. When $\phi=\frac{\pi}2$, we are pointing at the horizontal plane. When $\phi = \pi$, we are already pointing at the negative $z$-axis. Hence, we do not go beyond $\pi$.